# Opening a new parameterized window in Windows Forms using Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, winforms, castle-windsor

Let's say I have an application with a grid that allows you to look at all customers. You pick a customer row in the grid and click "Edit".

In non-IOC WinForms the event handler looks like this:

```
public void OnBtnEditClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var customer = grid.SelectedRow.Object as Customer;
    var dialog = new EditCustomerDialog(customer);
    dialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

If I am using Windsor as my container, my understanding is this would look something like:

```
// Injected by container and set in constructor of Form
private readonly IViewFactory _viewFactory;

public void OnBtnEditClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var customer = grid.SelectedRow.Object as Customer;
    var dialog = _viewFactory.CreateView<EditCustomerDialog>();
    dialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

What's the best way for the new form to know which "customer" it is dealing with? In the non-IOC version, you would just pass it as an argument. Should setter injection be used here or is there some more elegant way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the setter injection is a clean solution here because of yor factory contract. You have a single, generic factory method and it looks like it can be reused for different view types.

Passing parameters to the factory method so that it could be then used for constructor injection

```
_viewFactory.CreateView<ViewType>( params );
// factory uses params for constructor injection
```

looks like a code smell as these two, the generic parameter and the actual parameter list are not syntactically related in such call. In other words, it would be too easy to mix a wrong generic parameter with wrong parameter list.

On the other hand

```
ViewType view = _viewFactory.CreateView<ViewType>();
view.Param1 = ...;
```

looks ok, the view type is a strongly typed contract and there is no way to mismatch parameters.

But yet another approach would be to narrow the factory method

```
ViewType view = _viewFactory.CreateViewType( params );
```

i.e. have a bunch of factory methods in the factory, each responsible for specific view type and with full parameter list.

And the last idea, a parameter object, which is a trade of between the two mentioned alread - you have a single factory method but a hierarchy of parameters

```
ViewTypeParams params = new ViewTypeParams();
params.Param1 = value;

BaseView view = _viewFactory.CreateView( params );
```

Personally I would consider the 2nd approach, however, it depends on what is actually most important to you in your specific case.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance and your thought process which was helpful. I think I will stick with setter injection.